# Video Call API Europe

Tags: api, video-conferencing

We would like to develop a feature for our application, that allows our users (macOS, Windows or web applications) to **Video-Call** other people (remote healthcare) and are looking for an **API** to do so.

Since we're **Europe-Based** (GDPR) we would like to either self-host it, or have the guarantee, that only EU-Servers are used.

I have looked into [TokBox](https://tokbox.com/) and many others. From the functionality, tokbox would be perfect, but as far as I read their documentation, we cannot enforce European servers to be used.

Are there any suggestions from people who developed something like this?

Comment: Which programming language the API should be?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at BigBlueButton https://bigbluebutton.org/ .  Both free and Free, there is commercial support from multiple vendors (not sure on locations/GDPR stuff) or you can self-host.  Designed for education, it works really well both stand alone self hosted and as integrated and commercially supported by the LMS I was the administrator of for the past 6 years.

When I used it stand alone (10 years ago) the downside was that there was no included interface for creating "rooms" or "meetings", authentication, etc.

What it did have was a very nice and well written API that made doing all of that trivial.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I will take a look at it. What do you think of [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/)?